# Draw x,y coordinates using matrix graph

Tags: java, graph

I have been trying to draw x and y coordinates using matrix graph. For now, I have the graph being drawn and everything is ready. However, I would like to transform this into x,y points from an array like how data is.

Here is my code and what I have tried..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class graph1 extends JPanel {

    int[] data = { 21, 0, 0, 1, 86, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 };
    final int PAD = 20;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, PAD, PAD, h - PAD)); // Draw ordinate.
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, h - PAD, w - PAD, h - PAD)); // Draw abcissa.

        // Draw labels.
        Font font = g2.getFont();
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        LineMetrics lm = font.getLineMetrics("0", frc);
        float sh = lm.getAscent() + lm.getDescent();

        // Ordinate label.
        String s = "data";
        float sy = PAD + ((h - 2 * PAD) - s.length() * sh) / 2 + lm.getAscent();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            float sw = (float) font.getStringBounds(letter, frc).getWidth();
            float sx = (PAD - sw) / 2;
            g2.drawString(letter, sx, sy);
            sy += sh;
        }

        // Abcissa label.
        s = "x axis";
        sy = h - PAD + (PAD - sh) / 2 + lm.getAscent();
        float sw = (float) font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getWidth();
        float sx = (w - sw) / 2;
        g2.drawString(s, sx, sy);

        // Draw lines.
        double xInc = (double) (w - 2 * PAD) / (data.length - 1);
        double scale = (double) (h - 2 * PAD) / getMax();
        g2.setPaint(Color.green.darker());

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            double x1 = PAD + i * xInc;
            double y1 = h - PAD - scale * data[i];
            double x2 = PAD + (i + 1) * xInc;
            double y2 = h - PAD - scale * data[i + 1];
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        }

        // Mark data points.
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            double x = PAD + i * xInc;
            double y = h - PAD - scale * data[i];
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4));
        }
    }

    private int getMax() {
        int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] > max)
                max = data[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new graph1());
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: here]

All comments are much appreciated, and thanks for reading this!

Comment: It is unclear what you want to get. Where is your matrix? How should the graph look like? Maybe it helps if you add a handdrawn image how it should look like to clarify.

Comment: @jukzi the same as how it looks right now but I would like to have it drawn with multiple x,y points from array

Answer (score 1):

create a 2D array of Integers:

```
int[][] data= new int[][]{
  { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
};
```

surround

```
    // Mark data points.
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        double x = PAD + i * xInc;
        double y = h - PAD - scale * data[i];
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4));
    }
```

with a loop around the 2nd dimension:

```
    // Mark data points.
  for  (int j=0; j < data.length; j++){
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    for (int i = 0; i < data[j].length; i++) {
        double x = PAD + i * xInc;
        double y = h - PAD - scale * data[j][i];
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4));
    }
  }
```

complete code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.LineMetrics;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class graph1 extends JPanel {

    int[][] data = { { 21, 0, 0, 1, 86, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 },
            { 0, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 }, { 0, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 },
            { 1, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 }, { 86, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 },
            { 88, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 }, { 74, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 },
            { 87, 1, 3, 5, 234, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77, 61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18 } };
    final int PAD = 20;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, PAD, PAD, h - PAD)); // Draw ordinate.
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, h - PAD, w - PAD, h - PAD)); // Draw
                                                                    // abcissa.

        // Draw labels.
        Font font = g2.getFont();
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        LineMetrics lm = font.getLineMetrics("0", frc);
        float sh = lm.getAscent() + lm.getDescent();

        // Ordinate label.
        String s = "data";
        float sy = PAD + ((h - 2 * PAD) - s.length() * sh) / 2 + lm.getAscent();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            float sw = (float) font.getStringBounds(letter, frc).getWidth();
            float sx = (PAD - sw) / 2;
            g2.drawString(letter, sx, sy);
            sy += sh;
        }

        // Abcissa label.
        s = "x axis";
        sy = h - PAD + (PAD - sh) / 2 + lm.getAscent();
        float sw = (float) font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getWidth();
        float sx = (w - sw) / 2;
        g2.drawString(s, sx, sy);

        // Draw lines.
        double xInc = (double) (w - 2 * PAD) / (data.length - 1);
        double scale = (double) (h - 2 * PAD) / getMax();
        g2.setPaint(Color.green.darker());

        for (int j = 0; j < data.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data[j].length - 1; i++) {
                double x1 = PAD + i * xInc;
                double y1 = h - PAD - scale * data[j][i];
                double x2 = PAD + (i + 1) * xInc;
                double y2 = h - PAD - scale * data[j][i + 1];
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
            }

            // Mark data points.
            g2.setPaint(Color.red);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                double x = PAD + i * xInc;
                double y = h - PAD - scale * data[j][i];
                g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4));
            }
        }
    }

    private int getMax() {
        int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data[j].length; i++) {
                if (data[j][i] > max)
                    max = data[j][i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new graph1());
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but It doesn't work properly. Could you please paste the code? I really appreciate!

Comment: Drawing lines is the thing.

Comment: Thanks again but I have a question. I think the way it is calculated is wrong because in axis it is the relation between x,y and from what I see, x1,x2 aren't being checked from the array of values. Data should only be two sets as well. Please help!